# How can continuous time data from multiple individuals be cut so that no individual is represented more than once per interval?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

Sorry for the awkward question; it's an awkward problem.

**An example dataset with "actual" times**

```
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- tibble(
  ID = rep(1:5, each = 10),
  TIME = sample.int(n = 100, size = 50, replace = FALSE)) |>
  arrange(ID, TIME)
```

This example is drastically simplified but I think it illustrates the issue (and hopefully can be used to work out a solution). **Basically, I have time values from many individuals and I want to coerce the actual time values into consistent nominal times to facilitate analysis and visualization.**

The issue is that the actual values don't line up nicely; here's another example:

> **Times for Subject 1:** 0, 1, 1.5, 5, 6

> **Times for Subject 2:** 0, 2, 4, 5, 6

If I were to create a series of "nominal" times, it might look like this:

> **Nominal times:** 0, 2, 4, 5, 6

Notice that at least one value in Subject 1's time series does not fit into the nominal times. If I were to coerce that into time = 2, there would be multiple values for Subject 1 in the "time = 2" bin.

In a small dataset, I could just manually identify the optimal bins to make sure no data are lost, but I'm dealing with a very large dataset with tons of times that differ by inconsistent intervals (and some subjects are missing times altogether).

Ideally, I'd like a function similar to `cut()` that creates the minimal number of bins necessary to ensure that every sample fits into a bin, but which ensures:

- No bin has timepoints from an individual more than once
- No bin contains just one individual unless moving that value to a preexisting bin would involve too great of a change (say, > 2 time units)

**Anyone have any suggestions that don't rely on really complicated code? Bonus points for dplyr-friendly solutions.**

Comment: Here's a possible strategy. (1) Take individual 1's times as the first cutpoints. (2) For each individual, if more than one of his times fits in a single interval, add all but the first of those times to the cutpoints.

Comment: Thanks @dash2. That would be a good solution if there wasn't so much variability in the times; I'd end up with 1.014, 1.015, 1.016, etc. Currently relying on the ```cut()``` function to create the minimum number of groups that include all unique times.